# Android XML Layout or Java Coded

Tags: android, android-layout

I am starting to delve into Android Development and there is a lot of material online. The question is... What are the pro's and con's against the drag and drop XML design method vs coding the view manually? The only reason I ask on here is because online the views are mixed and they don't really back up what they're defending.

If I use the drag and drop method will I have issues further onto my development adventures? That is the thing that worries me the most... I don't want to learn the drag and drop method and then editting the XML to cater for my needs and then be handicapped by it.

Comment: Do not use drag and drop. because of in future if you want to change any alignment you can not manage easily\

Comment: I've personally _never_ used the drag and drop feature, and honestly, I'd advise you to just ignore it. Use the layout preview to see what the layout looks like, but only modify the layout in XML. That way, you can explicitly dictate how the views and view groups behave.

Answer (score 2):

For the beginner(s), I highly recommend not to use Drag and drop. We need to understand `XML`, to be comfortable with android widget. Understanding `XML` will come handy in future when creating custom `styles` and themes.

**Here are few pointers before you dive in android XML layout**

- Try sticking with `match_parent` and `wrap_content` while defining `android:layout_height` or `android:layout_width` if possible
- Make sure you have good understanding of `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout` and `FrameLayout` and how its child views are arranged.
- Forget about `ConstraintLayout`, `AppbarLayout` and similar advance layout at current.
- Try exploring `TextView`, `EditText`, `Button`, `ImageView` and `ProressBar` as far as possible.(This are most common widgets/views)
- Try avoiding any tutorial related to `ListView`, its deprecated. Try using `RecyclerView` instead, it is one of the important widget that would be used in regular basis.